# Find the simplest regex query to match a set of examples

Tags: regex, algorithm

The online service [Kimono](https://www.kimonolabs.com/) provides a GUI for a user to select
page elements and then uses the selected elements to create a regex which will match those selections. This regex can then be used to extract information from the same page at different points in time. The service is useful because you dont have to generate the regex query yourself and instead provide a set of example query matches which are then compiled into a query regex expression. The company was acquired and so the service is no longer available.

However the problem seems like an interesting problem and so my question is this: what algorithm is capable of turning a number of examples (both positive and negative are needed) in a large document into a regex which when applied will then match those examples?

Comment: Index the documents by page. Listen for user selections on documents. Insert the regex matchings into the appropriate page index? Seems like a general algorithm to me

Comment: This is far too broad for stack overflow.

Comment: @MacroMan no it's not. These data-structures and algorithms have names. They are well understood. The OP just doesn't know the terminology.

Comment: This is related to a question asked at cstheory: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1854/is-finding-the-minimum-regular-expression-an-np-complete-problem

Comment: @MacroMan Not too general at all. In fact its a pretty specific question. So specific that both z5h and templatetypedef knew exactly where I can find the answers.

Comment: Careful. `.*` will match all your examples, whatever they are, and it's a shortest-possible regex (unless your examples are all single-character strings, or a single empty string).  You presumably also want this regex not to match any other string!

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks. Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are typically implemented with NFAs and DFAs.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton

The process of finding the smallest DFA to represent a particular DFA is known as minimization.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization

This needs to be converted back into a regular expression.
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions

Comment: This doesn't address the question at hand. You're right that you can find a minimum-state DFA this way, but that doesn't guarantee you can find a minimum-length regex.

Comment: @templatetypedef The "simplest" regex was asked for. I think there's some leeway in the definition.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I'm not sure how this connects back to regular expressions. How would you go from a small DFA to a simple regex? The act of turning automata into regexes often introduces an enormous blowup in regex size.

Comment: @templatetypedef I see form your comment post that optimizing for regex length is much harder than DFA minimization. In any case, the OP seemed to be asking from a very elementary perspective. One where I thought pointing to reading material would be the best start. My assumption that a minimal DFA lead to a reasonably simple regex is wrong. I suspect in many practical cases it would generate something reasonable.